# Jquery Templeate, dropping last item off in the each

Tags: jquery

Currently I am using jquery templating with some json data, I have a couple images that I am getting and I would like to drop the last image that I am getting from my json data. Right now I have this coded ( this only a snippet of the spot I am having the problem at):

```
    <div class="altViews">
    <ul class="clearfix">
    {{each(i,addImage) AdditionalImages}}
        <li class="altImage">
            <img src="http://images.url.com/images/products/${addImage}" alt="${Name}" id="${addImage}"/>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

SO the main help I need is to be able to drop the last li, I just dont know how to use my index to do that.

Comment: Go into your data and remove the items *before* passing them onto the templating engine. Templates ought to be plug-and-play.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use an `{{if}}` statement:

```
<div class="altViews">
    <ul class="clearfix">
    {{each(i,addImage) AdditionalImages}}
        {{if i < AdditionalImages.length - 2}}
        <li class="altImage">
            <img src="http://images.url.com/images/products/${addImage}" alt="${Name}" id="${addImage}"/>
        </li>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That works pretty well but my issue is I might not know how many there are so.... Not sure I f this would work

Comment: `AdditionalImages.length` is the number of items passed into the template.

Comment: Duh, I am sorry glanced over it so fast. Thank you David

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
{{each AdditionalImages}}
    {{if (($index + 1) < AdditionalImages.length)}}
        <li class="altImage">
                    <img src="http://images.url.com/images/products/${addImage}" alt="${Name}" id="${addImage}"/>
        </li>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```